# Azure DevOps CI build running twice

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, pull-request

I have a pipeline setup in Azure Devops. I have remove the triggers from my YML file and I have added triggers to the Azure pipeline. I have a trigger for CI and a trigger for PR.
[image: CI Trigger Configuration]
[image: PR Trigger Configuration]
These are set to a specific branch and specific folder within my repository.

**When I commit code the CI build runs twice.**

[image: Build triggered twice]

I've looked everywhere for a settings. What might cause this?

Comment: do you have an open PR for this branch? since you enabled both, CI and PR validation, this would be expected I believe

Comment: @silent nope, no open PRs. When I PR against this branch I only get one build (as expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, you're using BitBucket repo for the pipeline.

Observe the last screenshot, both are CI triggers, but the version number is not in sequence: `20210825.17` and `2.0.0-debug.11504`. If it's triggered twice by azure devops trigger, the next number should be `20210825.18`.

Hence, please go to Bitbucket repo setting -> delete all existing webhooks, then:

1. code commit in bitbucket, is azure pipeline still triggered?
2. If it's not, edit the azure pipeline, trigger tab, click 'restore' button to restore webhook. Check again if it fixes.

[image]

3. If the issue persists,you can try to create a new test pipeline with same repo for a check.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Ignore the build numbers. The first step in my pipeline is to set the build number to the version number of the code. This step had run for the build that ran to completion, but the not for the build that I cancelled.

Comment: @MarkCooper, since you override the yaml trigger from UI, the trigger was related to two elements: 1. service connection 2. webhook. Hence, please try to delete webhook and restore webhook with the steps above, in addition, you can edit the pipeline -> 'Yaml' tab -> Get resources -> Change the service connection for authorization, you can create a new service connection to re-authorize. Let me know if it works, thanks.

Comment: @MarkCooper，greetings! Is there any update? would you please mark my reply as answer if it helps? Let me know if you have any queries. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be willing to bet (because I found this question when researching it happening to us) you have both a [CI Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#ci-triggers) on the build pipeline, and a [Build Validation Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation) (on the repo itself) for PRs that include the same branches.

It's non-intuitive that you can have triggers that call the same process defined in two such disparate places.